# Use of 'approot'

Tags: haskell, yesod

If I set the `approot` like the following

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Main where

import Yesod.Core

data Yello = Yello

mkYesod "Yello" [parseRoutes|
/home1 Home1R GET
/home2 Home2R GET
|]

instance Yesod Yello where
    approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:3000/v1"

getHome1R :: Handler Html
getHome1R = defaultLayout [whamlet|Homepage 01|]

getHome2R :: Handler Html
getHome2R = defaultLayout [whamlet|<a href=@{Home1R}>Homepage 02|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 Yello
```

then `@{Home1R}` get's rendered to `http://localhost:3000/v1/home1` **but** this little yesod-based web application is only reachable at `http://localhost:3000` (w/o the `/v1`).

1. What's the purpose of `approot`?
2. Where to set/ add `/v1`?

Comment: With the `approot` you specify exactly that, where your app is located, and thus what the root of an URL is. Typically one uses tooling like `nginx` to redirect correctly to the correct server.

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Just trying to get a Yesod "Hello world" (no scaffolding) running via nginx. Via nginx, I want `http://localhost` to give the "Welcome to nginx" site. Now `http://localhost/foo` shall serve some other application (just static HTML pages) and `http://localhost/bar` shall serve the Yesod "Hello world". What value do I have to set for `approot`? Just `approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:9000"`? And what shall be the configuration for nginx?

Comment: Fyi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391194/how-to-locally-run-a-yesod-web-app-via-nginx