# How to locally run a Yesod web app via Nginx?

Tags: haskell, nginx, yesod

On the Yesod site I have the following (excerpt):

```
staticFiles "assets/"

newtype App = App
    { appStatic :: Static
    }

instance Yesod App where
    approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:9000/yello"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    appStatic <- static "assets"
    warp 9000 $ App appStatic
```

So, I'm declaring that my little web application will be hosted at the prefix `yello`.

Now, I want to run this on Nginx ... but don't get the configuration right :(

I have the following `nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /yello/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
        }
        #location /assets {
        #    root /Users/nrm/Learning/Haskell/web/yesod/yello;
        #    expires max;
        #}
    }
}
```

My local source code is at `/Users/nrm/Learning/Haskell/web/yesod/yello`, so I first start `yello` and then run `nginx`:

At Terminal 1:

```
[/Users/nrm/Learning/Haskell/web/yesod/yello]
$ stack build
$ stack exec -- yello
```

At Terminal 2:

```
[/usr/local/etc/nginx]                                                             
$ nginx
```

Then at the browser, I enter `localhost/yello` and the result is

```
Not Found

/yelloyello/yello
```

and the URL in the address bar changed to `http://localhost/yelloyello/yello`.

What am i missing here?

**Update0**: Simplified `nginx.conf` according to https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite. Still does not work :(

**Update1**: With the following configurations it's working (note, no prefix in `approot`!):

```
staticFiles "assets/"

newtype App = App
    { appStatic :: Static
    }

instance Yesod App where
    approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:9000"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    appStatic <- static "assets"
    warp 9000 $ App appStatic
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location /yello/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
        }
    }
}
```

At Terminal 1:

```
[/Users/nrm/Learning/Haskell/web/yesod/yello]
$ stack build
$ stack exec -- yello
```

At Terminal 2:

```
[/usr/local/etc/nginx]                                                             
$ nginx
```

Then at the browser, enter `http://localhost/yello`.

Comment: OK, that’s weird. It’s running in Safari but not in Chrome!

W/o a prefix on the Yesod site `approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:9000”` and the following Nginx configuration `daemon off; events { worker_connections  1024; } http { server { listen 80; server_name  localhost; location /yello/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/; }}} Opening `http://localhost/yello` in Safari gives the correct site. But opening the same URL in Chrome, I get `http://localhost/yelloyello/yello`. That’s weird! Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args --disable-extensions --disable-plugins` also doesn't help.

Comment: OK, I shut down the web app as well as the nginx server. Then entered `http://localhost/yello/` in Chrome and got `http://localhost/yelloyello/yello`

Comment: Opened Chrome with a different account, then it worked. So all the mess is just about the fact that somehow my Google Chrome configuration is kind of corrupt. Will investigate...

Comment: Oh man... "Clear Browsing Data..." and "Basic" did the trick...